# Create video thumbnail in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working in a project in laravel
and I want to create thumbnail when upload video

I am following this artical

> https://packagist.org/packages/pawlox/video-thumbnail
>
> pawlox/video-thumbnail

when I call this

```
 $thumb = VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail(asset('public/stories/videos/21530251287.mp4'), asset("public/images/"), 'thumb.jpg', 2, 600, 600);
```

its return

```
Pawlox\VideoThumbnail\VideoThumbnail Object(
[FFMpeg:protected] => 
[videoObject:protected] => 
[videoURL:protected] => http://localhost/sunbay/yms/public/stories/2/videos/21530251287.mp4
[storageURL:protected] => http://localhost/sunbay/yms/public/images
[thumbName:protected] => thumb.jpg
[fullFile:protected] => http://localhost/sunbay/yms/public/images/thumb.jpg
[height:protected] => 600
[width:protected] => 600
[screenShotTime:protected] => 2 )
```

but thumb not generated.

Please let me know what wrong I am doing. and how to resolved it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **FFMpeg**
**For ubuntu 16.04:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

`asset` generates a URL, you need a file path, try:

```
$thumb = VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail(public_path('stories/videos/21530251287.mp4'), public_path("images/"), 'thumb.jpg', 2, 600, 600);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the thumbnail is not saving. It is actually created but not stored. If you check `/var/www/html/theevent/vendor/pawlox/video-thumbnail/src/VideoThumbnail.php` then you will see this method.

```
 public function createThumbnail($videoUrl, $storageUrl, $fileName, $second, $width = 640, $height = 480) {
        $this->videoURL = $videoUrl;

        $this->storageURL = $storageUrl;
        $this->thumbName = $fileName;
        $this->fullFile = "{$this->storageURL}/{$this->thumbName}";

        $this->screenShotTime = $second;

        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;

        try {
            $this->create();
            $this->thumbnail();
            $this->resizeCropImage($this->width, $this->height, $this->fullFile, $this->fullFile);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this;
    }



so u need to fix the file path by creating d folder for the file to be saved 

here my working code 

      $thumbnail_path=storage_path().'/app/public/thumbs';
                $file = $request->file('video');
               $thumbvideoPath  = storage_path('/app/public/videos/').$videoName;
                      $video_path       = $destination_path.'/'.$file_name;
                      $thumbnail_image  = $videoName.".jpg";

$thumbnail_status = VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail($thumbvideoPath,$thumbnail_path,$thumbnail_image, 10);

//dd($thumbnail_status);
   if($thumbnail_status)
   {
     echo "Thumbnail generated            ";
   }
   else
   {
     echo "thumbnail generation has failed";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart your xampp server.

Your are adding:

```
       FFMPEG="/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
       FFPROBE="/usr/bin/ffprobe"
```

to your env and after making changes in `.env` file you need to restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

I was also using this package to generate thumbnails and face errors continuously then I use this package and get rid of these errors.

```
https://packagist.org/packages/lakshmajim/thumbnail
```

or

```
https://github.com/lakshmaji/Thumbnail
```